# Spinner return null value

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

when i am selected spinner value then some time it return a true value and some time it return null value

My spinner code is

```
list.add("Please Select Approver Name");
list.add("bishnu");
list.add("bishnu");
list.add("bishnu");
list.add("bishnu");

  ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
          adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp1.setAdapter(adp1);
        sp1.setSelection(0);
```

Item Selected Listener

```
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                        strspin = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                    }
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(context, "value"+strspin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I am working on it past two day

Please Help Me how i can fix this problem

Comment: Move your `Toast.makeTest` at the end of the `onItemSelected` method.

Comment: it would be helpfull to see more of Your code. For example, where did You set Your adapter to the listview, where had You initialized Your listView and adapter etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Toast inside the onITemSelected method as below.

```
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                    strspin = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                   Toast.makeText(context, "value"+strspin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
```